# Bind backslash \ to forward delete using karabiner with DefaultKeyBinding.dict?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, keybindings, karabiner

This is pretty beyond me but hoping someone can help.
I typically change the <kbd>Fn</kbd> (or now Globe) modifier key to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in settings as this is my childhood on windows computers muscle memory at play.

I have subsequently succeeded in changing the behavior of <kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> (not <kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd> ) to paste rather than page down by using the follow code in Terminal

```
mkdir ~/Library/KeyBindings/

vi ~/Library/KeyBindings/DefaultKeyBinding.dict

"^v" = "noop:";
```

This came from a number of forums where people have noted that <kbd>Control</kbd> <kbd>V</kbd>  acts as page down.

NOW: My Windows muscle memory also means that the <kbd>\</kbd> key, under <kbd>Delete</kbd>, is where I expect to find <kbd>Forward Delete</kbd>. In the old days I would use Karabiner Elements to modify the key but on the new MacBook M2 Air it disables the Globe key modification that is in place in settings so just creates another problem.

However this is the code (below) that karabiner uses so I am wondering -
Can I just paste this into my `DefaultKeyBinding.Dict` or somehow apply it somewhere so that I don't need Karabiner?

```
{
  "title": "Backslash (\\) to forward delete. (Use Fn + \\ for default behavior)",
  "rules": [
    {
      "description": "Change Backslash (\\) to forward delete",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "key_code": "backslash"
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "delete_forward"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "Change option + \\ to delete next word",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "option"
              ]
            },
            "key_code": "backslash"
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "delete_forward",
              "modifiers": [
                "option"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "description": "Change command + \\ to delete forward whole line",
      "manipulators": [
        {
          "type": "basic",
          "from": {
            "modifiers": {
              "mandatory": [
                "command"
              ]
            },
            "key_code": "backslash"
          },
          "to": [
            {
              "key_code": "delete_forward",
              "modifiers": [
                "command"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: You're using Unix now.  Slash and backslash have very specific meanings.  My advice is to get used to the difference rather than remap your keyboard.   I also don't advise anyone to remap all the keys in macOS to Windows equivalents - you're going to run into issues.